# Bad char encoding with FileHelperEngine

Tags: c#, encoding, character-encoding

I'm trying to read strings from a .csv file through the **FileHelperEngine** library in this way:

```
        UTF8Encoding utf8 = new UTF8Encoding();
        var engine = new FileHelperEngine(typeof(TipologieMetadatiCsv), utf8);
```

and I've issues with accented chars, like:

Sofà -> "Sof�"

How this could be solved ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved in this way:

```
        TextReader textReader = new StreamReader(stream, Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1"));

        var engine = new FileHelperEngine(typeof(TipologieMetadatiCsv), Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1"));
```

Comment: Probably the file isn't in iso-8859-1 but is in windows-1252. There are little differences, like the support for the '€' symbol, and in general the windows-1252 is a superset of the iso-8859-1

Comment: so you suggest to use windows-1252 ?